# How to change https default port but not include it in the URL

Tags: google-chrome, web, tcp, ip, port

I have a website on 2 different servers. And I would like to access the site on server #1 by going to https://www.example.com/ (on port 80) and access it on server #2 by going to https://www.example.com:4567/

But the problem is that I need to hide the port number from the address bar. With port 80 it is hidden by default. But if I change it to a different port then it is visible. For example if I do **console.log(window.location.href)** on the server I will see https://www.example.com:4567/ (with port included).

Is it possible to tell Google Chrome that the default port is not 443 for HTTPS but instead 4567? I could not find anything in the settings that could do that.

Comment: The default HTTPS port is 443, and you cannot change that at all. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution for my problem. Although it requires that I access the website from a specific IP address.

I was able to set up port forwarding in my router in such a way that all incoming requests from my IP address get automatically forwarded to not only a local IP but also a specific port number.

[image]